# SQL joining wordpress tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I am struggling with an SQL query to join 3 tables to return specific results.

Anyone familiar with wordpress may be able to assist as I am using word press to power post interactions with the db behind the scenes but am building a custom UI. The three tables are: -

```
posts  (**ID**, post_title, post_content, post_modified_gmt)
term_relationships (**object_id**, term_taxonomy)
terms (**term_id**, name, slug)
```

I have got as far as..

```
 SELECT posts.post_title FROM posts
 INNER JOIN term_relationships
 ON posts.ID = term_relationships.object_id
```

Which returns a list of all the post titles that have a matching ID number in term_relationships. However term names are in the table 'terms' and the ID's don't match the other two tables. In the terms table the term_id refers to the name of the term, e.g

```
term_id = 2, name = blog
```

Basically I am trying to achieve a query whereby if I set the term_id = 2 it returns all the rows from the table posts that have the term relationship to blog, meaning the query returns all blog posts and I am completely lost!

Can anyone give me a few pointers? my mind is boggled.

Comment: You're leaving out an important table in the wordpress database structure `wp_term_taxonomy`. This is a table you'll need to link `wp_terms` and `wp_term_relationships`. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description. Also, it's not clear what you're asking at then end. You want all posts that have the term 'blog' associated with them?

Comment: Yes that's right, so if I tag the post with the category 'blog' in the wordpress back end I can run this query to return all posts with that term.

Comment: I don't need the taxonomy table because all the 'pages' are custom built I am only interested in categories for organising post displays on pages.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to achieve the result I was looking for with the following query, but would still appreciate some pointers should anyone stumble upon this and have the inclination :)

```
         SELECT * FROM posts
            INNER JOIN term_relationships
            ON posts.ID = term_relationships.object_id
         WHERE term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 2 
            AND posts.post_type = 'post' 
            AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
         ORDER BY posts.post_modified_gmt ASC
         LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: So you did need the `term_taxonomy`! ;) Glad you figured out the issue.